# defined a global var but Chrome Console returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

This is my code:

```
jQuery(function ($){
    var player = $('#player');
    var time = 0;

    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
    }

    player.bind('pause', function(){
        console.log('player was paused');
        console.log(player.currentTime);
        setCookie("time", player.currentTime, 2)
    });
});
```

I declared two variables (an object and a number). The object `player` gets defined correctly, but when I try to call `time` the console returns undefined.

Comment: Those aren't global; they're scoped to the function they're in.

Comment: you never log *time*

Comment: Do you mean it's `undefined` when you log it in the code above (which you don't, you log `player.currentTime` which probably doesn't make sense since `player` is the result of a jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared global variables. Both the values will be undefined in global scope. To have a global scope you may define like this.

```
var player = $('#player');
var time = 0;
jQuery(function ($){
    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
    }

    player.bind('pause', function(){
        console.log('player was paused');
        console.log(player.currentTime);
        setCookie("time", player.currentTime, 2)
    });
});
```

Comment: You probably don't want `player` to be *captured* outside of a DOMReady, though.

Comment: @DaveNewton That is right. In that case, the variable `player` may be declared in global scope and defined inside DOMReady

Answer (score -1):

You may really define it global?

```
jQuery(function ($){
var player = $('#player');
window.time = 0;

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
    }

player.bind('pause', function(){
    console.log('player was paused');
    console.log(player.currentTime);//what should curentTime be?
    setCookie("time", player.currentTime, 2);
    window.time=player.currentTime;//an example
});
});
```

Now it is really global...

```
//in the console
console.log(time);
```